# Front End for Running Talend Jobs

Tags: frontend, talend

I am looking for a front end for our operator to run our Talend jobs.  We do not want him to have the ability to delete or modify jobs.  Only to run them and monitor their results.  Any suggestions for tools for doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The subscription version of Talend (called Talend Integration Suite, or TIS) has precisely that.  It's a web-based console called Talend Administration Center (TAC) and it allows an operator to run jobs and monitor their results -- among many other things.  The permissions can be set in the way you described, so that the operator is not able to delete or modify the jobs.

Comment: you wouldn't happen to know of any free equivalents tot TIS would you?

Answer (score 2):

In my company we use [SOS Job Scheduler](http://www.sos-berlin.com/modules/cjaycontent/index.php?id=62&page=osource_scheduler_introduction_en.htm), which you can use with TOS out-of-the-box as a general diy scheduling solution. Just these days I'm working on a Talend Custom Component to integrate deeply between the first and the latter (like log-propagation, context parameter sharing and so on. Basically it let you use SOS API from a TOS job). I can speed-up and put on github in a few days, if you need :)

Comment: Thanks.  I actually was looking into SOS as a solution.  We ended up using Spago BI's dashboard as a tool for scheduling Talend jobs.  We are able to customize the interface and it just seemed to be a little easier to use than SOS.  I didn't find SOS's interface to be overly intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

You can export job as shall script (.sh) and anyone can execute that and will not able to delete those jobs.
To see the execution details put some tlog component into your talend jobs.
This is just a work around not the solution if you only have open studio (free version).

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Rundeck for manual and scheduled execution of Talend jobs . I find the job setup and scheduling to be far easier in Rundeck than in SpagoBI (which I frequently use for reports and BI).

You could also use something like automic (uc4) automation engine. It has fine grained security and is a commercial product . I've used it in the past for similar work.