# Talend administration center alternative

Tags: deployment, etl, talend

I'm new to talend, I've mostly developed all my ETL work in Visual studio and deployed to SSIS. Recently I've had to work with talend for sftp file downloads and REST api calls.

The way I scheduled these new talend jobs is by building in talend for windows and scheduling it on the server to run on schedule. My question is: Is there something similar like SSIS where I can deploy jobs to a server and monitor the jobs. Looks like Administration Center is for enterprise only.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was discussed in a similar thread 
[Front End for Running Talend Jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7448677/front-end-for-running-talend-jobs/34057452#34057452)

I suggest looking at Rundeck or SOS Job scheduler. There are plenty of commercial products which do the same thing, such as Automic (formerly UC4) automation engine or JAMS Scheduler. All of these are quite capable of running a job (locale or remote) by executing the shell script for a Talend job and collecting the console or log output .

I'm currently using Rundeck for Talend jobs. I've used Jams and Automation Engine previously for Kettle / PDI and other jobs.

Answer (score 0):

[Talend Administration Center](https://www.talendforge.org/tutorials/tutorial.php?idTuto=54) is not free, it's for entreprise version only, you can use [Quartz](https://quartz-scheduler.org/) as alternative, it has almost what you need to schedule and manage job dependencies.

Comment: The only info regarding how to use Quartz for scheduling is here:https://help.talend.com/reader/_kirWdGiwNgvHlXUtw8vGA/nbC9Hy5vU80NaxvekNEoyw but it's not the easiest to understand so if anyone knows some good examples that would be helpful.